# Time taken in changing surface tension

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, surface-tension

I had read some where that the water in glasses has a high surface tension, but in lota (It is sort of a spherical container) the surface tension is lower.

- How can I measure the water surface tension difference between
  container types?
- If I take the water from a glass and I put it into a lota, over what
  period of time will the surface tension of the water change?

This is a lota: 
[image: nearly-spherical brass vessel]

---

I have heard that we drink should have less surface tension, but this is not centric to the science of my question.  My thanks for your help.

Comment: The surface tension does not depend on the container. It is a property of the water/air interface. Can you post a link for the claim that surface tension is lower in a burbot. I tried Googling but all I found were articles [about the fish burbot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burbot).

Comment: @JohnRennie Sorry for that it is not burbot

Comment: A quick Google found claims that the lota reduces surface tension because it has a small opening. This isn't reducing surface tension, it's reducing **surface energy**. The surface tension is constant, which means that the greater the area of the air/water interface the greater the total surface energy. Having said this, if the lota is half full there will be a larger air/water interface area and therefore greater surface energy.

Comment: Can you link your source?

Comment: It could be vaguely related to the fact that surface tension changes with impurities and we should not drink impure water. But this is absurd. As pointed by John Surface tension is just a property of water/surface interface. Internet is filled with noobs

Comment: @Awesome I do not think that my source is of a noob, I am sort of sure that drinking water from lota is much more beneficial and the reason is scientific too... maybe this is not because of surface tension but there should be some scientific reason proving this....my source is from vagbat a great ayurvedic guru or something from the past, so i highly doubt that it can be untrue

Comment: @DakshShah You used the the term *more* Its relative. compared to what?

Comment: @Awesome compared to glass. Drinking water from lota is very very much better (beneficial) than drinking water from glass.

Comment: @DakshShah Can you cite the exact source? Did someone tell you or you read it somewhere?

Comment: @Awesome It was given in a lecture from Rajiv Dixit which had done a research on ayurveda and all and did scintific experiments to prove it (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMLH5qfMCjc) this is in which he is telling all this but it is in hindi :P

Comment: @Awesome Do you want me to translate it for you?

Comment: @DakshShah I am an indian

Comment: @Awesome did you see the vid? And if you do not believe in him, try searching from his other lectures, he has told about his research and all

Comment: @DakshShah You suggest to store water in lota and drink from glass or drink directly from it?

Comment: You should change the title

Comment: @DakshShah this is a mainstream-science-centric site, and as such you will find better response and dialogue on your questions if you refrain from exposing certain people to the possibility of science that they are not yet ready for.  Those who are researching for the possibility of new/old sciences will hear the root of your question, and you will still meet with the minds you hope to (while also getting straight answers from those otherwise-competent minds).

Comment: @NewAlexandria Sure

Comment: Also, whether or not it is healthier for you is probably more about biology than physics

Comment: @Jim I wanted to know the reason for it, involving physics not the bio one

Comment: Please use [chat] for further discussions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Surface tension of a liquid may change when something is mixed with it. For e.g. the substances like soaps, detergents, etc decrease the surface tension of water. See
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surfactant for more information.

Comment: Don't you think that it is absurd?

Comment: what is absurd?

Comment: Lota increases surface tension and hence decreases impurities? Does that make any sense?

Comment: No, not at all! Unless the metal absorbs any impurities. Does copper(or is it brass) exhibit any such effect?

Comment: I am not a chem expert but I can say it is not related to surface tension. It may just be an extra result in our experiment which is not related to our aim

Comment: @Awesome vessel shape influences circulation of fluid contents (as does the level/quantity of the contained liquid, etc).  Circulation can indeed affect suspensions. I am not saying that this will affect surface tension in all situations.  but, Just because you do not like the reason that DakshShah is investigating this does not mean that you should turn off your thinking.

Comment: @NewAlexandria I have not studied in much detail. Just about to enter college. Sorry if I was wrong.

Comment: I've also heard that drinking water stored overnight in copper vessel is beneficial. However, I don't believe it, and a proof would be nice.